# add a subplot to the plot produced by a previous function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've written a function that reads data from a csv file and plots it. Now I need to add a subplot with another part of the data from the same file, so I've tried to write a function that calls the first function and adds a subplot. When I do this, I get the two to show up as different figures. How can I suppress this and make both of them show in the same figure?

Here is a mockup of my code:

```
def timex(h_ratio = [3, 1]):

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

    total_height = h_ratio[0] + h_ratio[1]
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(total_height, 1)

    time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[:h_ratio[0], :])
    plt.plot(time, x)
    plot = plt.gcf
    plt.show()

    return time, x, y, plot, gs, h_ratio

def timeyx():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

    time, x, y, plot, gs, h_ratio = timex(h_ratio = [3, 1])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[h_ratio[1], :])
    plt.plot(time, y) 
    plt.show()

timeyx()
```

I realize that I have two plt.show() statements, but if I remove one that figure will not show at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether you need to use matplotlib.gridspec specifically or not, but you can use subplot2grid to make the job easy.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def timex():
    time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,0))
    ax1.plot(time, x)

    return time, x, y

def timeyx():

    time, x, y = timex()

    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,1))
    ax2.plot(time, y)

timeyx()
plt.show()
```

This produces one figure shown below with two subplots:

[image]